# Adapting Simple Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this very basic slider which works as it should - but when having multiple sliders on a page they all slide at the same time when 1 of the right or left buttons are clicked.

How do I make each of these unique to themselves?

Appreciate any help given

Thank you

Working example can be found here -> https://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl <-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
      moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
  $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: + slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next, a.control_prev_1, a.control_next_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_prev_1:hover, a.control_next:hover, a.control_next_1:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_prev_1 {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next, a.control_next_1 {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.slider_option > label {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="slider">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="control_prev"><</a>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></li>
      <li><img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></li>
      <li><img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></li>
      <li><img src="//farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></li>
    </ul>  
    </div>

  <div class="slider_option">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use stacksnippets instead of an external site, since you share all your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique to themselves"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code addresses elements based on HTML `id` atributes, which are supposed to be unique for single elements on a page.

Since you're using jQuery already, I recommend you go read up on structuring your functions as part of a [plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) that can be applied to multiple elements on a page.